# What are some application of finding largest eigenvalue numerically?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, soft-question, numerical-linear-algebra

I am interested in knowing some applications of approximating the largest eigenvalue of a large matrix using methods such as power method and Lanczos method and Arnoldi iteration... in domains such as machine learning and sciences. What are some examples? I thought of one application that is to approximate the condition number of a large matrix. However, for engineering and sciences I have no idea when they're used and as an applied mathematics student I am curious to know about these applications.

Comment: I had a small summer job a decade ago where I compiled and wrapped an Arnoldi package (it was called Arpack, written in Fortran, and they needed it to work with C#). I was, unfortunately, never curious enough to dig deeply into why they wanted me to do it. But I did hear "dimensionality reduction" mentioned. So some kind of optimisation problem, apparently. But don't ask me how large eigenvalues are actually useful for that.

Comment: Google's PageRank algorithm; see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936757/why-is-pagerank-an-eigenvector-problem), for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dominant eigenvalue determines the maximum growth rate on the norm of a vector when you apply the operator to it.   So if your largest eigenvalue is $M$ for a matrix $A$,  then you know for all vectors $v$,

$$\|Av\|\leq M\|v\|$$

with equality if $v$ is in the eigenspace for one of the eigenvalues of maximal norm.   This obviously helps us bound the possible growth, as well as knowing in what direction things grow in.

One interesting application I know of was in Conway's look and say sequence, where one takes a $92\times 92$ matrix,  finds a 21 dimensional invariant subspace where the eigenvalues are all norm 1 (so in that area it doesn't grow), then on the remaining $71\times 71$ matrix you get the dominant eigenvalue is Conway's Cosmological Constant.